# Checkbox not displays on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, checkbox

I cannot make chrome display correctly the checkboxes generated with the CakePHP form helper.

Labels are OK, but not checkbox can be seen, nor the value can be changed.
In the other web browsers it works OK.
Please see the attached screenshot.
Ideas ?

[image: as seen in firefox][image: as seen in chrome]

Comment: That's a pure CSS problem and not related to CakePHP. It might be a good idea to show what the inspector shows for the CSS or paste your whole CSS related to the checkboxes.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  It was, of course, a css problem.  I've defined height: 100% for input fields.  It seems that chrome handles this in a different way than other browsers do.
Removing that line, makes chrome display checkboxes ok.

Regards.
Facundo.